# How to loop through values in a data frame with the PrepText() command?

Tags: r, loops, text

I have a data frame that stores names of saved data frame objects in my R session:

```
col1 <- c("what is this", "how are you", "hello im good")
df <- data.frame(col1)
```

The `what is this` object looks like this:

```
title <- c("this is a cat", "this is a dog", "this is a dog")
body <- c("the cat is very cute", "who cares", "here is a bone")
`what is this` <- data.frame(title, body)
```

I want to be able to loop through all three object names in the `df` data frame using the `textnets` [package](https://sicss.io/2020/materials/day3-text-analysis/text-networks/rmarkdown/Text_Networks.html) and stack the `text_centrality` results on top of each other. I wrote the following code:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  prepped_header <- PrepText(df[row, "col1"], groupvar = "title", textvar = "body", node_type = "groups", tokenizer = "words", pos = "nouns", remove_stop_words = TRUE, compound_nouns = TRUE)
  
  header_text_network <- CreateTextnet(prepped_header)
  text_centrality <- TextCentrality(header_text_network)
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in PrepText(df[row, "col1"], groupvar = "title", textvar = "body",  : 
  unused arguments (groupvar = "title", textvar = "body", node_type = "groups", tokenizer = "words", pos = "nouns", remove_stop_words = TRUE, compound_nouns = TRUE)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you loaded the textnets package?

Comment: If the values of the col1 are object names to data created in the global env, you may need `get` i.e. `PrepText(get(df[row, "col1"]), groupvar = "title", textvar = "body", node_type = "groups", tokenizer = "words", pos = "nouns", remove_stop_words = TRUE, compound_nouns = TRUE)`  (not tested as this package is not in CRAN)